# Power Query throws: "We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Number." How do I embed a numeric parameter in the TSQL code of an M query?

Tags: type-conversion, concatenation, parameter-passing, powerquery, m

I try to parametrize TSQL code in the Power Query M language.

I defined a self-built parameter `TestID` in the menu bar at the top. The parameter is a numeric value. Embedding it with `[data_format_0] = "&TestID&")` throws the error:

> We cannot apply operator `&` to types Text and Number.
> Details:
> Operator=`&`
>
> `TestID = Excel.CurrentWorkbook() {[Name="TestID"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]`
>
> ```sql
> select ...   
> where  
> time@timestamp  
> between  
> (select distinct max([time@timestamp]) from [POD01EVENTLOG] where [data_format_4] = 1 and [data_format_0] = "&TestID&")  
> and  
> (select distinct max([time@timestamp]) + 60 from [POD01EVENTLOG] where [data_format_4] = 1 and [data_format_0] = "&TestID&")
> ```

And my Power Query M code is:

```m
let 
    TestID = Excel.CurrentWorkbook() {[Name="TestID"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    Source = Sql.Database("SERVERNAME", "DBNAME", 
    [Query="
SELECT *

from [POD01RAWDATA]

where 
time@timestamp 
between 
(select distinct max([time@timestamp]) from [POD01EVENTLOG] where [data_format_4] = 1 and [data_format_0] = "&TestID&")
and 
(select distinct max([time@timestamp]) + 60 from [POD01EVENTLOG] where [data_format_4] = 1 and [data_format_0] = "&TestID&")
"])

in
    Source
```

The question: If Power Query throws: "We cannot apply operator `&` to types Text and Number.", how do I concatenate the numeric parameter in the M string?

Comment: How is this relevant to SQL Server?

Comment: That is not powerquery M code. Post your real code from home ..advanced editor ...

Comment: The "&TestID&" is M code. It's embedded in the SQL query

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but the issue lies in M code, not the SQL as I can run the same code is MSSMS without the M code with no issues.

Comment: Just updated with the rest of the query that pertains to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't concatenate number and text so convert the testid to TEXT before concatenating it

```
" & Number.ToText(TestID,"D") & "
```

Comment: See I tried that before I posted on here and it didn't work, but let me try again!

Answer (score 1):

Or do

```
&Text.From(TestID)&
```